# Implications of cloning MS Win7 OS SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd, operating-systems, clone

What are the implications esp. with resp. to OS / application software licensing, bootability when cloning the MSFT OS (win7pro64) carrying msata SSD onto a larger msata SSD? 
Plan is to unbolt the msata SSD from the Win7 PC plug into msata-USB adapter plug that into an auxiliary computer (pref. running linux) using `dd` command to copy ssd to a file and then the file to the new ssd. Concern is if OS /software licensing is tied to OS boot disk hardware IDs that will not be preserved in the coning process.

Comment: Licensing is tied to hardware.

Comment: Some software is tied to a device based on specific hardware, but most is tied to other factors. Cloning a drive almost never causes a problem with standard MS software unless you swap out drives several times.